# Does the Healing Bonus item property increase Healing Done, or Healing Received?

Tags: pillars-of-eternity

I've found a few items, like Fulvano's Amulet pictured below, which have the **Healing Bonus** property; each states that it provides 1.15x healing. Which sounds great! Problem is, I don't know if it's Healing Done - in which case, I want to give it to my Priest and my Chanter, or Healing Received, in which case I want to give it to my Fighter or my Wizard.

Which is it?

[image: Fulvano's]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### It's healing received

It is very ambiguously stated within the game, and the natural assumption would be that you give it to your healer to make their healing spells more effective. However, if you look at the item, "Belt of Bountiful Healing" it has the same, "Healing bonus: +15% Healing done" as fulvano's amulet. But the full description states:

> While these belts provide no direct influence upon the injuries or fatigue of their wearers, the enchantments do lend additional power to those spells of mending and recuperation which strike it.

Clarifying that it affects incoming healing.

Answer (score 1):

The bonus is on healing cast, not healing received.

Comment: I don't know how to feel about that answer. I mean, it answers the question perfectly, sources possibly non-existent except for the game itself... And yet it doesn't really satisfy my curiosity on the topic.

Comment: Wouldn't make a lot of sense to have to put healing bonus gear on the entire party, rather than the one person who casts the heals.

Comment: @nosf I disagree, I have seen similar effects in other games implemented in both ways.